# 'cadence' has no installation candidate in Ubuntu Mate 20.04

Tags: mate, audio-jack

I recently updated to Ubuntu MATE 20.04 from 18.04 using 
`sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

My instance of `cadence` isnt working any longer. 
When I try to reinstall `cadence` I get the following errors.

```
Reading state information... Done
Package cadence is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'cadence' has no installation candidate
```

Any thoughts of how I can get 'cadence' back working on Mate 20.04?

I have followed the info on [kxstudio repositories page](https://kx.studio/Repositories).

Answer (score 3):

The package may not being found because the [KXStudio repositories](https://kx.studio/Repositories) were removed upon upgrading. Simply reinstalling the kxstudio-repos.deb file won't work. You need to remove and purge the file and then install again, as detailed in this bug report https://github.com/KXStudio/Repository/issues/235.

`sudo apt-get remove --purge kxstudio-repos`

`sudo apt-get install kxstudio-repos_10.0.3_all.deb`

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working on Ubuntu 20.04.4, it results in "no installation candidate" error.

Comment: Ah, of course. After following the above steps, make sure to do `sudo apt update` before trying to do `sudo apt install cadence`!

Answer (score 2):

This happened because of the fact that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is too fresh.

But as temporary solution you use a trick to install packages from 18.04 LTS on 20.04 LTS:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kxstudio-debian/apps
sudo sed -i "s/focal/bionic/" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kxstudio-debian-ubuntu-apps-focal.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cadence
```

I e-mailed to the KXStudio team to ask packaging for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Thank you for emailing the kxstudio team.  I rely on their packages a lot.  Unfortunately the above didnt work for me.

Comment: Please add error output to the question body.

Comment: I have tried this, and the error seems to be that Cadence starts, but it says "jackdbus is not available", so you can't really run anything with it.

Comment: Thank you. This solution seems to work.